# change div style when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JS Code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var mindist = 1000;
    var closest = '';
    $('#header').each(function(i, el){
        var thisdist = Math.abs(scrolltop - $(el).offset().top);
        if (thisdist < mindist) {
            closest = el.id;
            mindist = thisdist;
        }
    });
    if (closest != '') {
        $('#header').toggleClass('test');
    }
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="header.png" width="100%" style="max-width:1024px;" />
</div> <!-- header-topbar -->
```

When the user starts to scroll down the page I want the height of the header to be smaller and also the image to be smaller.

I tried this in my CSS:

```
.test {
    height: 100px;
}
```

but it doesn't change the height at all.

Comment: why $('#header').each? header is an ID and should only be there once

Comment: http://bit.ly/1v8pFWE

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

CSS:

```
<style>
.test img {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="header.png" width="100%" style="max-width:1024px;" />
    <p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p><p>this is a simple text</p>
</div> <!-- header-topbar -->
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? $('#header').addClass('test') : $('#header').removeClass('test');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Use timer function to know when scroll starts and stop

```
(function() {        
    var timer;
    $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#header').addClass("test");// set height to 100px
        timer = setTimeout( refresh , 15000 );
    });
    var refresh = function () { 
        $('#header').removeClass("test");
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            html,body{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                border:0px;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                }
            body{
                position:relative;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            #wrap{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                position:relative;
                overflow-y:auto;
                display:inline-block;
            }

        .test{
            height: 100px;
            display:block;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var position = 0;

            function redraw()
                {
                var height=$('#body').height();
                if(position>0)
                    {
                    $('#header').toggleClass('test',true);
                    }
                console.log(position); // see the output on the developer tool console
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
        <img src="header.png" width="100%" style="max-width:1024px;" />
        </div> <!-- header-topbar -->
        <br />
        <br />
        ... <!-- put as many break tags as you can to test it -->
        <br />
        <br />
        </div>
        <script>
        position = $('#wrap').scrollTop();
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('#wrap').scroll(function()
                {
                var scroll = $('#wrap').scrollTop();

                setTimeout('redraw()',5);

                position = scroll;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use `setTimeout()` to get the realtime value of the scrolling position.
Also, instead of using `toggleClass(className)`, use `toggleClass(className,switch)`.